# Automatically increase OpenShift SSH timeout

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, openshift-online-2

When I SSH into my gear on OpenShift the default SSH timeout is 300 seconds, which I find too short. I can run either of the following commands in the terminal to fix this:

```
export TMOUT=30000
unset TMOUT
```

However, doing this on each login is a chore and I sometimes forget. I don't appear to be able to edit `.bashrc`, and putting these commands in `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.bash_profile` doesn't work either.

I have resorted to echoing a reminder message from my `.bash_profile` and appending `export TMOUT=30000` to my bash history with `history -s "export TMOUT=30000"`. This, at least, makes it easier to run the command while also giving me a reminder.

But ideally this would happen automatically. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script to prompt you for name and ip and run:

> ssh -t name@ip 'export TMOUT=30000; bash -l'

Then, if you don't already have one, create a .bash_logout file to run "unset TMOUT"

I think this should work and make your life easier :)